# How to take image(s) when user happy and face detected using face-api

Tags: javascript, jquery, face-detection, face-api

I am using face-api library. https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js

I am trying to get a photo from the video when face-api recognizes face more than 0.5 and when the user happy more than 0.6. I find out how to get that info using face-api, but didn't know how to get a photo without user interaction and put it in some img element(base64 format of image).

Here is code example what I have till now:

```
<body>
<video id="video" width="720" height="560" autoplay muted></video>
<div id="screenshot">
    <img src="" style="display: none">
<script>
const video = document.getElementById('video')

Promise.all([
    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/face-api/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/face-api/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/face-api/models'),
    faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/face-api/models')
]).then(startVideo)

function startVideo() {
    navigator.getUserMedia(
        {video: {}},
        stream => video.srcObject = stream,
        err => console.error(err)
    )
}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
    const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video)
    document.body.append(canvas)
    const displaySize = {width: video.width, height: video.height}
    faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)
    setInterval(async () => {
        const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions()
        const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
        if (resizedDetections.length > 0 && resizedDetections[0].detection.score > 0.7 && resizedDetections[0].expressions.happy > 0.5) {
//HERE I NEED TO TAKE IMAGE FROM PHOTO
            }
        }, 100)
    })
    </script>
```

Can anybody help me with that part?

you can find html version of it [here](http://you%20can%20find%20html%20version%20of%20it%20here:%20https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Face-Detection-JavaScript):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find out a solution to this problem. I think someone will use it or help him to solve some problem or complete project :) I'll be glad if anybody uses it.

Add div with id `screenshot` in form where you like to store images and add this code:

```
 if (resizedDetections.length > 0 && resizedDetections[0].detection.score > 0.7 && resizedDetections[0].expressions.happy > 0.5) {
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);

    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');

    document.getElementById('screenshot').appendChild(img)
            }
```

this will add an image on your form so you can use it for sending it to the server-side part of the project.